# Question about Visual Studio 2010 stub generator

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, code-generation

Whenever I generate a stub method in VS 2010 I'm automatically getting a **private** stub by default..

Is there any way to change once and for all the default choice of the generator to internal for example?
Or I'm not allowed to interfere with the default generator setting and therefore if I want a change I must always do it only manually?

Thanks

Comment: Good question, maybe there is a template somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

? what method are you using for generating your stubs?  I usually just use the snippet "prop"(tab-tab) and it throws out public properties.

Failing that, you can write your own snippets.  http://www.visualstudiotutor.com/2010/02/create-snippet-visual-studio-2010/

Comment: I meant  that when I write in a Top down approach a method which is not exist I click generate method stub in class ___   and then the automatic setting appear...

Comment: That's not the normal behavior, are you sure you're not hitting the Field stub choice by mistake?